# How to change support library in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I'm using some animation (I think the PathMeasure() causes the problem, there is no other extraordinary thing in my code).

When I test my app in android 5.0+,there was no problem and worked well.
But when it came to android 4.4.4, there is nothing on the screen.
It didn't crash, but there was an error in logcat:

```
Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

I found this advice:

> ... any version < support library 21 the method does nothing... not crashing on old versions, rather than actually providing that functionality.
>   With support library 22.1 you can use.

How can I use support library 22.1? 
What's wrong with my current settings?

My build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asd.anim"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
     ...
}

depencencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Are you making use of `RippleDrawable` anywhere in your code? It wasn't added until API 21, so naturally isn't available to older API versions.

Comment: I'm not using directly `RippleDrawable`, but `PathMeasure` used it some way (or something like that) :D
But disabling the hardware-acceleration solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use support library 22.1?

Change the dependency to:
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'`

You'll also need to change the `targetSdkVersion` and the `compileSdkVersion` to 22, consequently any other support libraries must be changed to versions `22.*.*`

You can find the revision history of support library here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: While this is certainly a direct answer to the OP's question, it doesn't address the root cause of the issue the OP is experiencing, nor is it particularly good advice in general. Downgrading support libraries is a last resort, particularly in cases like this where the version would change significantly (24.2.1 to 22.1). Amongst other things, the OP would lose all of the bug fixes, new features, optimisations and other improvements made in the versions since 22.1. In my experience these kinds of issues often have different root causes, and these are worth exploring before changing versions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved.
For future reference:

There was no need to change support library.
I found on android.developer.com, that

> On KITKAT and earlier releases, the resulting path may not
>   display on a **hardware-accelerated** Canvas.

Despite of it wasn't enabled, I needed to disable manually in Manifest: `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`